# Disable connection alert (Multipeer connectivity)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios7.1, multipeer-connectivity

Since iOS 7.1 Apple removed:

```
- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
       withContext:(NSData *)context
 invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler
```

and added:

```
- (void)advertiserAssitantWillPresentInvitation:(MCAdvertiserAssistant *)advertiserAssistant;

- (void)advertiserAssistantDidDismissInvitation:(MCAdvertiserAssistant *)advertiserAssistant;
```

Is there any ability not to show this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate instead of MCAdvertiserAssistant and MCAdvertiserAssistantDelegate. MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser allows you to handle acceptance or rejection of the invitation programmatically via advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer. For example:

```
- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)theAdvertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)directorPeerId withContext:(NSData *)invitationData invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler
{
    // accept the invitation and stop advertising
    invitationHandler(YES, self.session);
    [self.advertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
    self.advertiser = nil;
}
```

See the Apple docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html