# how to disable connection alert (ios multipeer connectivity framework)

Tags: ios, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

**I found this:** [[Disable connection alert (Multipeer connectivity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919905/disable-connection-alert-multipeer-connectivity?rq=1][1])

And the code from that is:

```
 - (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)theAdvertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)directorPeerId withContext:(NSData *)invitationData invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler
{
    // accept the invitation and stop advertising
    invitationHandler(YES, self.session);
    [self.advertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
    self.advertiser = nil;
}
```

But I don't know how to make this code to work, where should it be implemented and how to trigger it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some snippets on what I do:

On one device - start the browser

```
_serviceBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
                                                   serviceType:_sessionName];

[_serviceBrowser startBrowsingForPeers];
```

On the other device - start the advertiser

```
_serviceAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
                                                           discoveryInfo:nil
                                                             serviceType:_sessionName];
[_serviceAdvertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
```

These services implement delegate functions to advise your app of a possible connection. Here the browser is advised of an advertiser and now invites the peer to join in a session

```
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID     withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:_session withContext:nil timeout:30.0];

}
```

The advertiser then responds

```
- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:    (MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler
{
    invitationHandler(YES, _session);
}
```

Now you will receive a session delegate call to advise you of the state of your peer connectivity. At this point you should be connected - no "real" user interaction required.

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state
```

Answer (score -1):

That method is called on a delegate that implements the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate protocol.

In order to receive an invitation to join a session, you need to advertise your willingness to do so. For example:

```
MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"Peer Name"];

// Here we set a nearby service advertiser that tells nearby peers that this app is willing to join sessions of a specified type.
self.advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:peerID discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:@"myservice"];
self.advertiser.delegate = self;
[self.advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
```

When a nearby browsing peers hears you, it may issue an invitation to join a session and when it does so, the method you mention will be called on the delegate and you can accept with the code you have quoted.